# WPF doesn't load images correctly

Tags: wpf

I have some icons in my WPF project to make the application more user friendly. WPF shows all icons on my computer but when I run the app on other computers it will show some of icons but not all of them. How can I fix it?

Update:

```
<Image Source="Office/Add-Female-User.ico" Stretch="None" />
```

I'm sure that all images are accessible because some of them are visible.

Comment: Are you sure all images can be found in the application resources when deployed to the other machines?

Comment: Can u please explain more... put some pictures here from you're apps

Comment: Please provide some code on how you load the pictures, your resource settings for the images, your usage of the pictures (perhaps in XAML)

Comment: Seems like you are referencing a local file rather than a resource. try adding the images as resources. or deliver the images along with your application

Comment: @MareInfinitus I just created a new folder called office and added icons to it. The Source of image points to that folder.

Comment: What are the file type of your images? Can they all be found by the application? when running in VS in debug mode you can look at the output and it will tell you if it can't find any resources.

Comment: @Grenter All of images are .ico files. Actually it finds all of the icons. There's nothing useful in Output Window.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your images (in your image controls) as Content not Resource. I suspect the problem is your images aren't copied to the output dir. View properties on missing image files and set build action to Content and Copy to output dir to Copy if newer.

For resource referencing see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx.

Comment: Of course I've copied files to output dir, but it just shows some of the images. i.e: I have images {A,B,C,D}, on some computers it shows A and B, but on the other computer it show B and C. Sounds strange to me.